how can I add filter to search bar of website by j.s
i have question in search bar .
in a page I have at least 30 product .
i will add filter that when client search the name of product ,product show .
i tried to craete filter but I couldnt write correct structure.
does anyone can help me ,I become happy.

How did you try to create the filter? We can't help debug code without seeing the code. Please include a minimal reproducible example in your question.

dear Im not very basic but I have some problem in create  an online shope . is it possible for you to send your phone or email address for help to me .?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you can try the following code if products listed in html list
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}


I created small json for myself . i don't know how can I add filter to json data
